# how to remove the class from parent div in keyup using react js

Tags: reactjs

I am having set of form fields, when i click on the submit button i adding error message class for each input textbox parent div this all are working fine,
my problem is when i keyup the textbox i need to remove the error message class using **reactjs**

```
<div class="form-blk">
   <label class="f-row error-msg">
     <input type="text" required />
   </label>
</div>
```

my div structure is like this, for validation i am using npm validator module

Comment: if your are using react replace `class` with `className`

Comment: you see the error in console ?

Comment: yes i am using like this className  only for example i wrote like that, i have no idea

Comment: so where do you see the `error message class`

Comment: <label className="f-row error-msg">

Comment: so where do you see the `error message class` and what error you see ?

Comment: i need to remove the className (error-msg) on keyUp

Comment: i just use to highlight the textbox in red color

Comment: ok you want to remove it

Comment: okay with the inline css you can do or introduce a new class

Comment: Try this

` function getCompState(){
    return {
     keyUp : false
    }
  }
   class Example extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = getCompState();
     }
     render(){
      var class_new = 'error-msg';
      if(this.state.keyUp ){ 
       class_new = 'class_new_defined'
      }
      return(
        <div className="form-blk">
          <label className={"f-row "+class_new}>
           <input type="text" required />
          </label>
        </div>
       )
     }
}`

Css 

`.class_new{}`

Answer (score 0):

So with the limited data provided in the question, this should give you some direction.

***Declare a state for the state change on the keyUp:***

```
 var state = {
      isKeyUp: false,
 }


updateKeyUpState() {
  this.setState( function( prevState) {
    return {
      isKeyUp: !prevState.isKeyUp
    }
  })
}
```

**Your Render function:**

```
render() {
    <button type="submit" onkeyup={updateKeyUpState}> SUBMIT </button>
      <div class="form-blk">
       <label className={this.state.isKeyUp ? 'f-row': 'f-row error-msg'}>
         <input type="text" required />
       </label>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`function getCompState(){return {keyUp : false}}
 class Example extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = getCompState();
     }
     render(){
      var class_new = 'error-msg';
      if(this.state.keyUp ){ 
       class_new = 'class_new_defined'
      }
        return(
        <div className="form-blk">
          <label className={"f-row "+class_new}>
           <input type="text" required />
          </label>
        </div>
        )
     }
   }`

Css

`.class_new{}`